# ClickHouse give user Access Rights only for several tables in database

Tags: permissions, clickhouse

I have two databases in Clickhouse:

- test
- test2

Tables in this DBs created by query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test.Migrations3 ( date Date DEFAULT toDate(now()), id UInt8, time UInt64) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/shard/test/Migrations3', 'clickhouse1', date, (id, time), 8192);
```

and I create two users for these databases. 
User permissions like this:

```xml
        <user>
            <password>pass</password>
            <networks incl="networks" replace="replace">
                <ip>::/0</ip>
                <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
            </networks>
            <!-- Settings profile for user. -->
            <profile>default</profile>
            <!-- Quota for user. -->
            <quota>default</quota>

        </user>
```

I got some data in these tables it was inserted like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO test.Migrations3 (date) VALUES (689);
```

Now I want to create new readonly user with access to database test, but only for table Migrations3 in this DB, not for all tables in database. 
I read documentation and I can't find how to setup this access.

Now I try to use these permissions:

```xml
<user1>
    <databases>
        <test>
            <Migrations3>
                <filter>id = 1</filter>
            </Migrations3>
        </test>
    </databases>

    <password>pass</password>
            <networks incl="networks" replace="replace">
                <ip>::/0</ip>
                <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
            </networks>
            <!-- Settings profile for user. -->
            <profile>readonly</profile>
            <!-- Quota for user. -->
            <quota>default</quota>
<allow_databases>
<database>test</database>
</allow_databases>

</user1>
```

When I run `select * from test.Migrations3` I see all rows, but I already setup filter in permissions only show id -eq 1

What I do wrong?

Comment: Please read this and improve the quality of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

sorry, but currently you can set access right to whole database
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/access_rights/
but you can restrict access to tables over row level security
as described here https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/settings_users/#user-name-databases

```xml
<user1>
<databases>
    <database_name>
        <!-- filter all rows from table -->
        <table1>
            <filter>1 = 0</filter>
        </table1>
    </database_name>
</databases>
</user1>
```

Comment: When I run ```select * from test.Migrations3``` I see all rows, but I already setup filter in permissions only show id -eq 1
I add my permissions to question
What I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure you run query from user1 ?
could you run ```SELECT currentUser()``` ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure .I can't connect to another DB, but I cat select everything in DB where I got permissions

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration forces that user user1 can only see the rows of table1 as the result of SELECT queries, where the value of the id field is 1000.

```xml
<user1>
<databases>
    <database_name>
        <table1>
            <filter>id = 1000</filter>
        </table1>
    </database_name>
</databases>
</user1>
```

The filter can be any expression resulting in a UInt8-type value. It usually contains comparisons and logical operators. Rows from database_name.table1 where filter results to 0 are not returned for this user. The filtering is incompatible with PREWHERE operations and disables WHERE→PREWHERE optimization.

Comment: Please add explanatory text to your answer. Learn more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24068740).

Comment: When I run ```select * from test.Migrations3``` I see all rows, but I already setup filter in permissions only show id -eq 1
I add my permissions to question
What I do wrong?

Comment: what version clickhouse do you use ?
please run ```SELECT version()``` ?

Comment: Version : 18.12.17

Comment: could you upgrade your clickhouse installation? as i know row level security added in 19.x version